# The inverse process to XmlSlurper

Tags: xml, groovy

I need to process some fields of a type of XML files and write the data back to XML in my current project. `XmlSlurper` is great in the sense of reading in an XML file. However, is there an equally convenient way in groovy to write the content from `XmlSlurper` back to XML? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Mataniko is right, consider this:

```
import groovy.xml.*

def xmlText = '''<items>
    <media>
        <id>1</id>
        <title>Hello</title>
    </media>
</items>'''

// Parse the XML into a GPathResult
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText( xmlText )

// Change the id to 4
xml.media.id = '4'

// Print it all back out
println XmlUtil.serialize( new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind { mkp.yield xml } )
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the MarkupBuilder class: [Creating XML using Groovy's MarkupBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Creating+XML+using+Groovy%27s+MarkupBuilder)

A simple usage:

```
def writer = new StringWriter()
def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
xml.items() {
    media{
        id(1)
        title("Hello")
   }
}
```

output:

```
<items>
    <media>
        <id>1</id>
        <title>Hello</title>
    </media>
</items>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am aware of the MarkupBuilder class. However, it is too cumbersome to me to write down the full structure of the XML as a closure. I probably can do it programmatically, but I wouldn't qualify that as convenient as `XmlSlurper`.

Comment: @JBT If you've ever had to build XML pre-markupbuilder, you'd classify it as convenient ;-)

Comment: @JBT Do you already have the XML structure? you can follow the DomToGroovy example in the link above to generate the markup. Otherwise you'd have to do it with regular Java.

Comment: @Mataniko Thanks for the tip. tim_yates's solution solved my problem.